# SQL JOIN - taking all left rows with grouping

Tags: sql, join, relation

So, I have tables named **files** and **folders** with ids and usual relation between them: file.folder_id = folder.id

Additionally, some of files/folders could be ignored by field **ignore**.

I'm trying to get list of folders and counts of files in corresponding folders.
My first approach worked fine but missed empty folders:

```
SELECT folders.id, folders.name, count(files.id) kount
FROM folders, files

WHERE folders.site_id=111
AND files.ignored=0
AND folders.ignored=0 
AND files.site_id=111
AND files.folder_id=folders.id

GROUP BY folders.name 
ORDER BY folders.name
```

So I look for LEFT JOIN

```
SELECT folders.id, folders.name, count(files.id) kount
FROM folders 


LEFT JOIN files 
ON files.folder_id=folders.id

WHERE folders.site_id=111
AND folders.ignored=0
AND files.ignored=0
AND files.site_id=111


GROUP BY folders.name 
ORDER BY folders.name
```

but again - empty folders are missing. What I'm doing wrong?

Comment: The `files.ignored=0` and `files.site_id=111` conditions in the WHERE clause effectively turn this into an INNER JOIN, because conditions in the WHERE clause are required to be satisfied in order for a row to be returned. As @juergend points out below, these should be moved into the ON clause of the OUTER JOIN. Because  you're limiting the values of `folders.site_id` and `folders.ignored` in the WHERE clause to the values you need from `files` your ON could be `ON files.folder_id = folders.id and files.ignored = folders.ignored and files.site_id = folders.site_id`. Best of luck.

Comment: You typically GROUP BY the columns you select, except those who are arguments to set functions. (I.e. `GROUP BY folders.id, folders.name`.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to put the conditions filtering the joined table directly into the `left join`

```
SELECT folders.id, folders.name, count(files.id) kount
FROM folders 
LEFT JOIN files ON files.folder_id=folders.id
               AND files.ignored=0
               AND files.site_id=111
WHERE folders.site_id=111
AND folders.ignored=0
GROUP BY folders.name 
ORDER BY folders.name
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
SELECT folders.id, folders.name, count(files.id) kount
FROM folders 


LEFT JOIN files 
ON files.folder_id=folders.id
AND files.ignored=0
AND files.site_id=111

WHERE folders.site_id=111
AND folders.ignored=0



GROUP BY folders.name 
ORDER BY folders.name
```